# Delay when extracting email

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

i am using scrapy to collect some data and i need to delay the code when extracting email. So not the entire code but only when it reaches the email extraction part. Any help is very appreciated.

```
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


# item class included here
class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://asheville.craigslist.org/bab/5078377070.html"
    ]

    BASE_URL = 'http://asheville.craigslist.org/'


    def parse_contact(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["attr"] = "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='anonemail']//text()").extract())
        return item
```

Comment: you can use DOWNLOAD_DELAY option.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) for this. It "suspend[s] execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds."

Comment: Where should i put time.sleep() exactly ?